# UISearchController SearchBar jumps down a couple of pixels on touch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I've got a `UISearchController` who's `SearchBar` is being added (and later removed) from my `NavigationController.TitleView`. When it's added it displays fine but as soon as I touch it, it jumps down a few pixels (as seen in the before-and-after below)

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3C0M.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjhEv.png)

Here's the code.

```
    protected event Action<string> SearchChanged;
    protected UISearchController Search { get; private set; }
    protected bool IsShowingSearch { get; private set; }

    public BaseViewController() : base(NSObjectFlag.Empty) { }

    public override void ViewDidLoad() {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;

        this.Search = new UISearchController((UIViewController)null);
        this.Search.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;
        this.Search.SearchBar.Placeholder = "Search...";
        ((UITextField)this.Search.SearchBar.ValueForKey(new NSString("_searchField"))).TextColor = UIColor.White;
        this.Search.SearchBar.ShowsCancelButton = true;
        this.Search.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
        this.Search.DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
        this.Search.ObscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
        this.Search.SearchBar.TextChanged += this._searchTextChanged;
        this.Search.SearchBar.CancelButtonClicked += (_, e) => this.HideSearch();

        this._setNavigationBar();
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    }

    private void _searchTextChanged(object sender, UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs e) => this.SearchChanged?.Invoke(e.SearchText);

    protected void ShowSearch() {
        this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            this.IsShowingSearch = true;
            this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(new UIBarButtonItem[0], true);
            this.NavigationItem.TitleView = this.Search.SearchBar;
        });
    }
    protected void HideSearch() {
        this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            this.Search.SearchBar.TextChanged -= this._searchTextChanged;
            this.Search.SearchBar.Text = "";
            this.NavigationItem.TitleView = null;
            this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(this.RightBarButtons.ToArray(), true);
            this.IsShowingSearch = false;
        });
    }
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        this.DefinesPresentationContext = true;
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated) {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        this.DefinesPresentationContext = false;
    }

    private void _setNavigationBar() {
        this.NavigationItem.Title = this.NavigationTitle ?? "Application";
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = Colors.ACCENT;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
        };
        if (this.RightBarButtons != null) {
            this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(this.RightBarButtons.ToArray(), true);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done some configuration in `_setNavigationBar()`. This issue won't happen in my side, tested it in a blank project. Also what's your ios version?

Comment: Added the `_setNavigationBar()` code at the bottom of the snippet